# Rails 4 Form Validation Issue Using Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-validate

I have a an invitation form that I've created some custom messages using the JQuery Validation Plugin.  The issues I'm having is when the form is submitted, the custom fields show correctly. However, if I submit the form the second time the line items are hidden.  Any idea why the validator is changing these items to hide upon the subsequent submittal?

```
**_form.html.erb**

  <section id="invitations-dropmodule" class="invitations-dropmodule dropmodule">
  <h3 class="invitations-title">Share the love with your family!</h3>
     <div id="errorContainer">
        <p id="errorHeader">Please correct the following errors:</p>
        <ul />
      </div>
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: invitation_path(resource_name), html: {method: :post, id: 'invitations-form', class: 'invitations-form'}) do |f| %>

      <%= f.input :full_name, label: false, placeholder: "Family Member's Name", input_html: { maxlength: 30, size: 40, value: nil } %>

      <%= f.input :email, label: false, placeholder: "Their Email Address", input_html: { value: nil } %>

      <div class="radio_buttons">
      <%= f.label "Their Gender:"%>
      <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, [["male", "male"] ,["female", "female"]], :first, :last, {:item_wrapper_class => ''}, {:class => "with-gap" } %>
      </div>

      <%= f.input :invitation_relation, label: false, :include_blank => 'I am this person\'s: ', selected: "I am this person's", collection: relation_types, label_method: :humanize, input_html: { class: "browser-default dropmodule__input-select" } %>

      <%= submit_tag "Send Invitation" %>
  <% end %>

</section>
```

Here's the .js file:

```
// Add Invite Form validation
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#invitations-form').validate({
      rules : {
       "user[full_name]" : {
        required : true
       },
       "user[email]" : {
       required : true
       },
       "user[invitation_relation]" : {
       required : true
       },
     },
     messages: {
       "user[full_name]": "Name is required",
       "user[email]": "Email is required",
       "user[invitation_relation]": "Relation is required",
     },
     errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
     errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
     wrapper: 'li'
   }); // end validate
  }); // end ready
```

Upon first submittal things works as expected:
[image]

The second submittal hides the line items:
[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

Rendered HTML Markup:

```
 <a data-activate="#invitations-dropmodule" class="dropmodule-btn invitations-btn right hide-on-med-and-down" title="Invite a Family Member"><i class="icon-mail"></i><span>invite</span></a>

<section id="invitations-dropmodule" class="invitations-dropmodule dropmodule">
  <h3 class="invitations-title">Share the love with your family!</h3>
  <!-- <form id="invitations-form" name="invitations" action="index.html" method="post" class="invitations-form">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Invitation">
  </form> -->
  <div id="errorContainer">
      <p id="errorHeader">Please correct the following errors:</p>
      <ul />
  </div>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/invitation" class="simple_form invitations-form" id="invitations-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

      <div class="input string optional user_full_name"><input class="string optional" id="user_full_name" maxlength="30" name="user[full_name]" placeholder="Family Member&#39;s Name" size="40" type="text" /></div>

      <div class="input email optional user_email"><input class="string email optional" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="Their Email Address" type="email" /></div>

      <div class="radio_buttons">
      <label class="string optional control-label" for="user_Their Gender:">Their gender:</label>
      <span class=""><input checked="checked" class="with-gap" id="user_gender_male" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="male" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_gender_male">male</label></span><span class=""><input class="with-gap" id="user_gender_female" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="female" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_gender_female">female</label></span>
      </div>

      <div class="input select optional user_invitation_relation"><select class="select optional browser-default dropmodule__input-select" id="user_invitation_relation" name="user[invitation_relation]"><option value="">I am this person&#39;s: </option>
<option value="great_grandmother">Great grandmother</option>
<option value="great_grandfather">Great grandfather</option>
<option value="grandmother">Grandmother</option>
<option value="grandfather">Grandfather</option>
<option value="mom">Mom</option>
<option value="dad">Dad</option>
<option value="wife">Wife</option>
<option value="husband">Husband</option>
<option value="aunt">Aunt</option>
<option value="uncle">Uncle</option>
<option value="sister">Sister</option>
<option value="brother">Brother</option>
<option value="cousin">Cousin</option>
<option value="daughter">Daughter</option>
<option value="son">Son</option>
<option value="niece">Niece</option>
<option value="nephew">Nephew</option>
<option value="granddaughter">Granddaughter</option>
<option value="grandson">Grandson</option>
<option value="great_granddaughter">Great granddaughter</option>
<option value="great_grandson">Great grandson</option></select></div>

      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Send Invitation" />
</form>
  </section>
```

Comment: Please only post the ***rendered*** HTML markup.  The JavaScript does not care about which framework was used to generate the page; it only cares about what's on it.

Comment: Unless you're using `.ajax()` (you have not shown any), the page would be reloaded or redirected after a form submission and then you would not see this issue as the page is starting over from scratch.  Otherwise, show enough **rendered** code so that we can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Well, that's the issue, Sparky, I don't know where it's being called again b/c I don't see any ajax call.  And, it could care about it, b/c turbolinks in Rails can play a part, which is why I added Rails as part of my question.  If you're trying to helpful please specify what I should be looking for and I'd gladly give you what you need.   Believe me, I'm not trying to stump anyone here - just trying to find an answer to a problem that has haunted me for a few days.

Comment: Of course I'm trying to be helpful, but you also have to help us... show the **rendered** HTML markup as originally requested.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sparky.  I appreciate the help.  I want to give you what you want.  When you say *rendered* mark up, I think you mean what my Rails code is rendering.  I thought that was the console output that I took a picture of, but maybe you mean the form html markup?  What's protocol?  Throw it in a gist or just edit my answer to include it?

Comment: Sparky, I threw it in EDIT in case this is what you want.  If's a big page, so if you want the entire page I'll throw it in a gist unless you specify otherwise.